# sonar project.properties to ignore files containing a regular expression

Tags: regex, sonarqube

I am trying to exclude files containing generated code in a sonar project.properties file.
I have added the following to `project.properties`.

```
sonar.issue.ignore.allfile=.*generated.*,.*GeneratedCodeAttribute.*
```

I get the following error:
ERROR: Caused by: Exclusions > Issues : Invalid format. The field does not define a regular expression: null

I have tried a lot of combinations. None of these work, same error.

```
sonar.issue.ignore.allfile=file:generated
sonar.issue.ignore.allfile=generated
sonar.issue.ignore.allfile=regex:generated

etc...
```

Any ideas on how to set this property in a `project.properties` file?
I am aware that this can be done in the user interface, I need the project file syntax for multiple exclusions. I have read the source code, but cannot figure out what's missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [Documentation here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) (Emphasis is mine)

> You can have SonarQube ignore issues on certain components and against
>   certain coding rules. Go to Configuration > Settings > Exclusions >
>   Issues.
>   **Note that the properties below can only be set through the web interface because they are multi-valued.**

Comment: Is there another way to ignore files based on a property? Failing that is there a configuration file that can be edited programmatically?

Comment: @Jim I'm unsure on what you mean by property

Comment: I mean is there any way to add regular expressions to any kind of property in a project.properties file that will result in files containing generated code to be ignored

Comment: @Jim none I'm aware of. We're using an old version of Sonar so I can't test, but maybe adding the exclusions and having a look into the project file after can be of some help ?

Comment: You *can* ignore files based on a property. See @Techtwaddle's answer.

Comment: @Disco3 I'm really unsure the answer works for the OP as he's looking to ignore files from their content, not their class or path.

Comment: You are right @Tensibai - I missed the word "contains". I thought they were actual filenames/paths

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the propertie `sonar.issue.ignore.allfile` to ignore all issues on file by setting the *project.properties* file as followed:

```
sonar.issue.ignore.allfile=r1
sonar.issue.ignore.allfile.r1.fileRegexp=GeneratedFile
```

As documented:
**If this regular expression is found in a file, then the whole file is ignored.**

means you'll need to set the regex, GeneratedFile for example, in the files that you want to be ignored.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Specifying the r1 is not in the documentation that I can see, do you by any chance know how to specify multiple conditions that can be used to match files? For example, how to specify /r1/ and /r2/?

Answer (score 2):

Check the last section in the link given by @Tensibai. Using sonar.exclusions in the project-properties file should work.

```
# Exclude all classes ending by "Bean"
# Matches org/sonar.api/MyBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyOtherBean.java, org/sonar/util/MyDTO.java, etc.
sonar.exclusions=**/*Bean.java,**/*DTO.java

# Exclude all classes in the "src/main/java/org/sonar" directory
# Matches src/main/java/org/sonar/MyClass.java, src/main/java/org/sonar/MyOtherClass.java
# But does not match src/main/java/org/sonar/util/MyClassUtil.java
sonar.exclusions=src/main/java/org/sonar/*
```