# Sonar Qube Ignore specific rule on files contains specific string (by regular expression)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I wanted to configure my SonarQube [v8.9.6.50800] scan to ignore Specific rule e.g. `squid:S1172` from classes which contains a specific string e.g. `implements BillingApi`.

To set this up I need to use some configuration?! that will accept a regular expression, let's say: `.* implements [^{]*Api` and rule.

I'm aware of the option to exclude specific rule for file path pattern as explained here: [SonarQube define "Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria" in maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56423040/2143846) 
Or the option to exclude all rules in a file as explained here: [sonar project.properties to ignore files containing a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34151866/2143846)

But I need to narrow the scope to exclude **specific rule** from **file contains some regex**.